# UPDATE table after LEFT JOIN

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN with some conditions. The code I'm using for that is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT ADS, Unit, Quantity, ZXY FROM TABLE1) as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ADS, Name, Unit_U, Price FROM TABLE2) as B
    ON ((A.ADS = B.ADS OR A.ADS = B.Name) and A.Unit = B.Unit_U) COLLATE nocase
```

Doing this I arrive to print the result, but the table is not updated (if I close the connection and restart it, I don't see the last column).

Even if I do a print of the column 'Price' selecting the table 1, I get an error saying that the column doesn't exists.

Here the example that I'm trying to solve :

**TABLE 1**

```
   ADS   Unit   Quantity   ZXY
--------------------------------------
    1     KG        2      None
    2     KG        1      None
    3     KG        3      None
    4     KG        5      None
    5     KG        7      None
    6     KG        1      None
```

**TABLE 2**

```
    ADS   Name   Unit_U    Price
--------------------------------------
     1     15      KG      7.00
     25    2       KG      8.00
     3     14      KG      5.00
     25    4       G       8.00
```

**TABLE AFTER LEFT JOIN**

```
    ADS   Unit   Quantity   ZXY   Price
   --------------------------------------
     1     KG        2      None   7.00
     2     KG        1      None   8.00
     3     KG        3      None   5.00
     4     KG        5      None   None
     5     KG        7      None   None
     6     KG        1      None   None
```

How can I UPDATE de table and save the modifications after the LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

Comment: Which table do you want to update?

Comment: Table one. I would like to see the column "Price" even if I close the connection and reconnect after.

Answer (score 2):

First add a `Price` column to `TABLE1`:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD COLUMN Price INTEGER;
```

Then run the following update to populate the `Price` column with values from `TABLE2`, if available:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
SET Price = (SELECT Price FROM TABLE2
             WHERE
                 (LOWER(t1.ADS) = LOWER(t2.ADS) OR LOWER(t1.ADS) = LOWER(t2.Name)) AND
                 LOWER(t1.Unit) = LOWER(t2.Unit_U))
```

SQLite does not support update joins and using a subquery is an alternative.

**Update:**

One way to do case insensitive comparisons of your fields is to compare the lowercase version of the left and right hand sides.

Comment: And what can I do to make the comparison into the conditions case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Just use update query as follows

Update `table name`
set `all the required columns in the table_to_be_updated set to individual columns in the join query`

Comment: The problem is that the column 'Price' does not exist in table 1 before the LEFT JOIN

Comment: Do an alter table to add the price column and then update it